# Migrating from TFS to VSS: Why does the wizard only pick one destination project?

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe, vssconverter

I'm migrating from VSS to TFS. I ran through the Wizard and it seemed to move the data over successfully. But I'm wondering:

The wizard only had me select *one* destination project. Now I migrating an entire VSS repo with tons of projects. I don't understand why there's only one project now? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: One or more team projects are hosted in one team project collection. And normally, you can put many projects into one or more team project based on your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "team project" in Team Foundation Server is basically a portfolio of related applications. You can (and should) have multiple applications in one team project. It's doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: But these applications are not necessarily related, except that they were all made by our company... So you've got, for instance, a corporate intranet and employee self service web portal. These don't both belong in the same TFS project do they?

Comment: It depends. The current thought is that you should keep all of your code in the same team project and then restrict access to source control via the use of teams, which also allows you to roll up work items across different teams for easier reporting.

Comment: Ok, if it's all under one project, then how to do you specify which SLN a work item is for?

Comment: A work item isn't for a solution, it's for a commit.

Comment: Gotcha. Some people online actually recommend that you put your whole team's repo under one project... Idk maybe it's not that bad. http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/09/05/153944.aspx